# JavaScript returning issue

Tags: javascript

I am using a javascript function, at the end of function I am returning this:

```
return {
     events : [{"id":1, "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12), "end": new Date(year,     
month, day, 13, 35),"title":"New Event"}] 
};
```

This is just 1 event, but if I want to add more events eg:

```
return {
     events : [{"id":1, "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12), "end": new 
Date(year,month, day, 13, 35),"title":"Lunch with Mike"}, {"id":2, "start": new  
Date(year,
month, day, 12), "end": new Date(year, month, day, 13, 35),"title":"New Event 2"}]
  };
```

This is hard coded, but I get records from DB, using these records i created a string similar which is similar to above format and passes it, it doesn't work.
example:

```
var EString = '{"id":1, "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12), "end": new Date(year, 
month, day, 13, 35),"title":"Lunch with Mike"}';
return {
     events : [EString]
  };
```

Comment: I recall there was some json.stringify or something, try googling it ,ur event is json format maybe u should convert it to string

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't help. What is the expected behaviour and what do you observe instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `JSON.stringify()`

```
 var EString = '{"id":1, "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12), "end": new Date(year, 
 month, day, 13, 35),"title":"Lunch with Mike"}';

 var jsonString = JSON.stringify(EString);
 return {
 events : [jsonString]
 };
```

**OR**

Try with `eval()`.

The `eval()` function evaluates or executes an argument.

```
var EString = '{"id":1, "start": new Date(year, month, day, 12), "end": new Date(year, 
month, day, 13, 35),"title":"Lunch with Mike"}';

var arrayOfObjects = eval(EString);
return {
 events : [arrayOfObjects]
};
```